# Matching a value to a field in XML using XQuery

Tags: sql, xml, xquery

I have a bunch of rows in a database that all contain an element that looks like the following

```
<ModuleData ModuleFieldGU="4dcdde21-40c6-4d1a-9fe1-1841935d3a68">
 <DateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</DateTime>
 <Boolean>false</Boolean>
 <Int>0</Int>
 <Varchar>Test District</Varchar>
 <GUID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</GUID>
 <Modified>true</Modified>
 </ModuleData>
```

I need to look across all of these and match where the varchar element/node is set to a certain value.

I've tried both of the followuing, and neither seem to be working for me

```
SELECT 
    Data.Element.value('(@Varchar)[1]', 'varchar(255)') as UserEmail 
    FROM
        ModuleData
    CROSS APPLY
        XML_DATA.nodes('/ModuleData') AS Data(Element)
    WHERE
    Data.Element.value('(@Varchar)[1]', 'varchar(255)') = @UserEmail
```

and

```
SELECT 
   CAST(XML_DATA.query('data(/ModuleData[@Varchar])') as varchar(255)) as UserEmail
FROM 
   ModuleData
WHERE 
   XML_DATA.exist('/ModuleData[@Varchar = sql:variable("@UserEmail")]') = 1
```

but it isn't working.  I'm not really up to speed with the finer points of using XQuery to get data out of XML.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct XPath should be:

```
/ModuleData/Varchar
```

Because it's an element, not an attribute.